# Función IF() en PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Estoy tratando de realizar una división entre dos celdas, pero quiero validar que el denominador no esté en cero para que no devuelva error. 
Estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente:

```
$sheetFirst->setCellValue("D$i", "=IF(B$i;C$i/B$i;0");
```

Dónde `$i` es la fila.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Agregale una condición que evalue que tu denominador no sea igual a 0, antes de setear un valor en tu celda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya me solucioné el problema. El separador de argumentos era la

> (,) coma

además me faltó el ´)´ paréntesis de la función.

Comment: Si llegaste a solucionar, podrías marcar como solucionado la respuesta que te ayudo. Gracias

Comment: @josego Hasta dentro de dos días no podrá marcar su propia respuesta como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Según el [soporte de office](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/C%C3%B3mo-corregir-un-error-%C2%A1DIV-0-3a5a18a9-8d80-4ebb-a908-39e759a009a5), la formula es de esta forma:

```
=IF( C2/B2,0)
```

Por lo tanto la forma correcta sería:

```
 $sheetFirst->setCellValue("D$i", "=IF(C$i/B$i,0)");
```